# jQuery accordion - link to specific tab

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs, accordion, hyperlink, containers

I'm new to jQuery and before I embark on a project I would like to know if it is possible to link to part 2 or 3 of this demo from an external page.

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/multipart/

or have an anchor on each page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks